Calculate the angle $α^\circ$ if $BE=2AE$.
Calculate $α^∘$ if $BE=2AE$.

(Answer:$26o30′$)
I have the solution below but I would like a solution with auxiliary lines and using approximate right triangles
$tgα=\frac{BE}{BC}=\frac{2 AE}{BC}$
$tg 2α=\frac{BC}{AB}=\frac{BC}{3 AE}$
$tgα tg2α=\frac{2}{3}$
$tg2 α=\frac{2 tgα}{1−tg^2α}$
$\frac{2 tg^2α}{1−tg2α}=\frac{2}{3}⇒tgα=0.5⇒α=26º30′$

Let $a=BC, b=CA, c=AB$ be the side lengths of the triangle. Let the A-angle bisector intersect side $BC$ at $D$. Let $x=BD \implies a-x=CD$.
By the angle bisector theorem we have $\frac{a-x}{x}=\frac{b}{c}\implies \frac{a}{x}=\frac{b}{c}+1$.
Also, note that the triangles $BDA$ and $BEC$ are similar by $AA$ criterion $\implies ax=\frac{2c^2}{3}$
So we have $$b^2-c^2=a^2=ax\cdot\frac{a}{x}=\frac{2c^2}{3}\cdot\frac{b}{c}+1$$
Now, solving the quadratic in $\frac cb$ we get $$\frac cb=\frac 35$$ which inmediatly implies $$\frac ca=\frac 34$$ by the pythagorean theorem.
Finally $$\tan(\alpha)=\frac{BE}{BC}=\frac 23\cdot\frac ca=\frac  {2}{3}\cdot \frac 34=\frac 12$$

Veru good  thamls for help

The goal is to show that $ABC$ has side lengths $3:4:5$ and $BEC$ has side lengths $1:2:\sqrt{5}$, from which we can get $\tan \alpha = \frac{1}{2}$ and apply the "approximate right triangle" (which is my loose interpretation of what OP means, and may or may not be what they intended).
Construct the perpendicular at $C$ to $BC$. Let it intersect the perpendicular bisector of $EC$ at $D$.
By construction, $ DE = DC$ and $ \angle DCB = 90^\circ$, so the circle centered at $D$ with radius $DC$ is tangential to $BC$. Hence $ \angle EDC = 2 \angle EBC = 2 \alpha$.
Now $\angle EAC = \angle EDC$ so $AECD$ is a cyclic quad. And since $EA \parallel CD$, $AECD$ is an isosceles trapezium, with $AC = ED$.
Let $AE = 1, BE = 2, AC = x$. Then $BC^2 = ( x^2 - 9 ) $
Let the foot of the perpendicular from $E$ to $CD$ be $F$. Then $ED^2 = DF^2 + FE^2  = (DC - BE) ^2 + (BC)^2 = (x-2)^2 + (x^2 - 9)$.
Then $x^2 = AC^2 = ED^2 = (x-2)^2 + (x^2 - 9)$ gives us $ x = 5, -1$ (reject negative value).
Hence, $ABC$ is the $3:4:5$ triangle and $BEC$ is a $1:2:\sqrt{5}$ triangle as desired.

The idea is as you thought, to use approximate right triangles... Why $∠EDC=2∠EBC=2α$?
In the part $ED^2=EF^2+FE^2$The correct one is $ED2=DF^2+FE^2$
Why $∠EAC=∠EDC$?

1/ Alternate angle segment + Angle at center is twice angle at circumference. 2/ Fixed the typo. 3/ Because they are both $ 2\alpha$.

Thanks for explanation
